# Loop through url's without a wildcard

Tags: python, selenium, url, wildcard

I am confused with this one.The Python code is for looping through urls using a wildcard* that replaces only the unique id for every match. Problem with this url pattern http://www.sportal.de/fussball/bundesliga/spielernoten-bayern-muenchen-fc-schalke-04-1-spieltag-2020-2021-20138500, is that text to be wildcarded stands between invariant part of url and the id. I am new to coding universe and really appreciate any help. Complete code is [here](https://github.com/otavio-s-s/data_science/blob/master/Premier%20League%20Scraping/Premier_league_scraper.py)

```
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

errors = []
season = []
for id in range(20138500, 20138501):
    # Opening the connection and grabbing the page
    my_url = f'http://www.sportal.de/fussball/bundesliga/spielernoten*{id}'
    option = Options()
    option.headless = False
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=option)
    driver.get(my_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser should know exact URL. You have to specify entire url

```
 my_url ="http://www.sportal.de/fussball/bundesliga/spielernoten-bayern-muenchen-fc-schalke-04-1-spieltag-2020-2021-"+str(id)
```